# Zope ZODB FileStorage: Data.fs doesn't pack enough

Tags: python, plone, zodb

I've been dealing with a problem on my Data.fs. It went from 5Gb 6 months ago to almost 10Gb now so I've tried to purge Data.fs.

First, I've put  portal_purgepolicy in the ZMI from 20 to 3. I've changed all my types in my plone CMS to avoid versioning on them. Then I've tried to pack my Data.fs with param 0 but it didn't change its size.

I've used fstest.py and fsrefs.py to check my FileStorage integrity and they didn't find any corrupted data.

I've tried this python script

```
>>> import ZODB
>>> from ZODB.FileStorage import FileStorage
>>> bad = FileStorage('Data.fs')
>>> good = FileStorage('Undamaged.fs')
>>> good.copyTransactionsFrom(bad, verbose=True)    
>>> good.close()
```

and then tried to repack but no change at all, still 10 Gb. I actually try with fsrecover but I see it as a lost cause since there is no corrupted data raised by fstest or fsrefs.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: How do you know there's not actually 10GB of data in there?

Comment: I am not sure, but do you need to run some kind of manual operation to purge the versioning data or does it happen automatically?

Comment: Here are some tools to peek into ZODB data: http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/persistency/persistent.html#measuring-persistent-object-sizes

Comment: AFAIK, changing the purge policy does not purge old versions unfortunately... I wish it were documented how the versioning works better and in which cases and how versions are purged.